# JLabel Location- JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I want to put an image label at certain coordinates on the screen.
I used the code below, but it doesn't work.
Also, when adding the commented line to the code, it gives an error

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EmiloLadderSnack
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Graphics g;
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("EmiloLadderSnack");
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
        BufferedImage img=null;
        try
        {
            img=ImageIO.read(new File("/media/01CCE00FA6888D80/Achieve/Eclipse/EmiloLadderSnack/src/photo.jpg"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            //g.drawString(e.toString(), 0, 0);
        }
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel(icon);
        lbl.setLocation(50, 50);
        panel.add(lbl);
        lbl.setLocation(50, 50);
    }
}
```

Please, help me fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

You should first add components to the frame and then call `pack()`, `setSize()` or `setVisible()`. In your case, you're adding `ImageIcon` to the panel after the frame is already visible. Adding `panel.revalidate();` should solve the immediate problem. However, it is best if you go through [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) tutorial first.

As for the second question, `Graphics` object is not initialized. Moreover, this is not how `Graphics` should be used. If you want to draw a string on the component's surface, override [paintComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) and use the provided `Graphics` object. See [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details. Otherwise, if the intent is to simply notify user about the error, you could use [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). The relevant tutorial is [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Also, using absolute layout can be very difficult. Check out [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand different layout managers and their basic use.

Answer (score 0):

```
setVisible(true);
```

should write at the end of, adding all components to Frame.

or else write the

```
panel.revalidate();
```

after adding the components to panel.

Your code is here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EmiloLadderSnack
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Graphics g;
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("EmiloLadderSnack");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);

    frame.add(panel);
    BufferedImage img=null;
    try
    {
        img=ImageIO.read(new File("/media/01CCE00FA6888D80/Achieve/Eclipse/EmiloLadderSnack/src/photo.jpg"));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //g.drawString(e.toString(), 0, 0);
    }
    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
    JLabel lbl=new JLabel(icon);
    lbl.setLocation(50, 50);
    panel.add(lbl);
    lbl.setLocation(50, 50);
    frame.setVisible(true);//put it here
}
}
```